# How can I compress json data returned from the backend?

Tags: json, compression, backend, bson, minimize

I have a big (nearly 66mb) json data returned from an database. I want to compress it and reduce the file size. **BSON was a good option for the server but it slows the client because of decoding process**. What are your suggestions to minimize json data?

Comment: I don't think is smart to send such amount of data to the client in one big json. Why don't you split it and send subsets on demand on the client?

Comment: I know but I can't directly split because we may lose valuable information. Can i use stream for that work?

Comment: [Brotli](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli), [Gzip](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) etcetera. You should listen to what @DA suggested though.